# Why the order of the application of the middleware is important to the body parsing?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code to initialize an express server and start serving requests.
The init() takes care of initialized environmental variables and the setLogger is setting some middleware as well.

The following example is working:

```
const app = express();

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));

init().then(async () => {

  await setLogger(app, RequestLabelManager.getInstance(), !!process.env.K_SERVICE);


  app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

  app.use(routes);

  app.use(apiErrorHandler());

  app.listen(app.get("port"), (): void => {
    console.log(` Express server started at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
  });

});
```

Now, I tried to move the initialization of the middlware inside the function like this

```
const app = express();

init().then(async () => {

  await setLogger(app, RequestLabelManager.getInstance(), !!process.env.K_SERVICE);

  app.options('*', cors());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

  app.use(routes);

  app.use(apiErrorHandler());

  app.listen(app.get("port"), (): void => {
    console.log(` Express server started at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
  });

});
```

But whenever the request is handled, the body is not parsed and req.body is an empty object.

After some other changes, we noticed how this example is working:

```
const app = express();

init().then(async () => {


  app.options('*', cors());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

  await setLogger(app, RequestLabelManager.getInstance(), !!process.env.K_SERVICE);

  app.use(routes);

  app.use(apiErrorHandler());

  app.listen(app.get("port"), (): void => {
    console.log(` Express server started at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
  });

});
```

Looks like there is something related the execution of an async operation (setLogger) that somehow makes the use of the parsing middleware irrelevant.

Does anyone know what this can be caused by?

I am expecting the order to be irrelevant when applying these middleware

Comment: What does `setLogger` do?